# What is CCU in photon Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, real-time-multiplayer

I can't understand Photo Engine CCU meaning and how to count it for my multiplayer game.

Can anyone Explain how photon count CCU.

Comment: It's simply how many users a currently active in your application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a programming question really, but the [Photon Licence Terms](https://dashboard.photonengine.com/en-US/Account/LicenseTerms) say this:

> concurrently active users that are logged into the Licensed Software per one Customer Application("CCU")

So one application or game has a maximum amount of users that may be logged on at the same time, and that is the CCU number.

Comment: worth noting that in Fusion, if you use multipeering, each *peer* is counted as one CCU. so one "Customer Application" can have multiple CCUs. I dont know why they used the term 'customer application' there; it sounds misleading